# (A little bit) Beyond the E-recursive

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory, proof-theory

The *E-recursive functions* are a particular generalization of classical recursion theory to the entire set-theoretic universe, $V$. They are defined via a schemes: see Sacks' *[$E$-recursive intuitions](http://www.math.harvard.edu/%7Esacks/erecint.pdf)*. It is easy to see that any $E$-recursive function is $\Sigma_1$-definable over $V$. However, the converse is not true.

Fortunately, there *is* a nice characterization of the $E$-recursive functions in terms of definability: this is shown by van de Wiele in *[Recursive Dilators and Generalized Recursion](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0049-237X%2808%2971893-7)* (in *Proceedings of Herbrand Symposium*, 1982), which states:

> $f: V\rightarrow V$ is $E$-recursive iff $f$ is **uniformly $\Sigma_1$**: that is, iff there is a single $\Sigma_1$-formula $\varphi$ such that, for every admissible set $A$, $\varphi^A=f\upharpoonright A$.

See Sacks' book *Higher Recursion Theory*, chapter XIII page 325 ([Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Higher-Recursion-Theory/chapter/Chapter-XIII-E-Recursively-Enumerable-Degrees/pl/1235422645?tab=ChapterArticleLink)), for a proof (due to Slaman). See also

- T. A. Slaman, *$\Sigma_1$ Definitions with Parameters*, Journal of Symbolic Logic **51** No. 2 (1986) pp. 453–461, https://doi.org/10.2307/2274069, [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274069)

for the natural extension of the theorem to oracle $E$-recursion.

My question is about a natural weakening of this definition: what happens if we require $f$ to be uniformly $\Sigma_1$, not across all admissible sets, but only across some smaller family of "nice" sets?

> **Definition**. For $n\in\omega$, a function $f: V\rightarrow V$ is *(E, n)-recursive* if $f$ is uniformly $\Sigma_1$ over the $n$-admissible sets: that is, iff there is a single $\Sigma_1$-formula $\varphi$ such that, for every $n$-admissible set $A$, $\varphi^A=f\upharpoonright A$.

(We can keep going past $\omega$, but here things get tricky - there's a few different things we can do, and it's not obvious to me what the right one is.)

On the one hand, we're not going too far afield here: all the functions we're looking at are still $\Sigma_1$ over $V$! On the other hand, looking at the proof of van de Wiele's theorem, it seems like we should be getting *some* extra power. So my question is, broadly: what is known about this method of "slicing" the $\Sigma_1$-on-$V$ functions? In particular:

- Are there $(E, n+1)$-recursive functions which are not $(E, n)$-recursive? (Presumably the answer is yes, but I don't see how to construct them.)
- How messy do things get? E.g., is there a reasonable description of the $(E, 2)$-recursive functions?

Comment: A note on tags: the "proof theory" tag is because the original proof of van de Wiele's theorem was via $\Pi^1_2$ logic, and proof theory might have something to say here. The "descriptive set theory" tag is a wild guess on my part.

Comment: Have you considered the functions (parametrized by $n$) mapping $x$ to the least $\Sigma_n$-admissible containing $x$?  They might distinguish between these classes.